# Is there any vars.yaml that ansible by default loads it?

Tags: ansible

I do `include_vars: defaults.yaml` in most of my playbooks, is there any file that ansible will load by default? so that I can put my default vars into there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no default variables file for playbooks.

There are defaults for roles in `<playbook_path>/roles/<myrole>/defaults/main.yml`.

Usual way to supply some common variables for you playbook is to use group vars for special group `all`.
Place them into: `<playbook_path>/group_vars/all/common.yml`